# Android ProGuard obfuscating specific classes

Tags: android, proguard

I need ProGuard only for the purpose of obfuscating specific classes. I tried to proguard all but I'm having problems making the application work properly.
How should I define the proguard-project.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Steps:-

1) Create a `proguard.cfg` file and place at the top directory of the project

2) In `project.properties` enable proguard something like this

```
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

The example proguard.cfg is

```
-optimizationpasses 5

#When not preverifing in a case-insensitive filing system, such as Windows. Because this tool unpacks your processed jars, you should then use:
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames

#Specifies not to ignore non-public library classes. As of version 4.5, this is the default setting
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses

#Preverification is irrelevant for the dex compiler and the Dalvik VM, so we can switch it off with the -dontpreverify option.
-dontpreverify

#Specifies to write out some more information during processing. If the program terminates with an exception, this option will print out the entire stack trace, instead of just the exception message.
-verbose

#The -optimizations option disables some arithmetic simplifications that Dalvik 1.0 and 1.5 can't handle. Note that the Dalvik VM also can't handle aggressive overloading (of static fields).
#To understand or change this check http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/optimizations.html
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

#To repackage classes on a single package
#-repackageclasses ''

#Uncomment if using annotations to keep them.
#-keepattributes *Annotation*

#Keep classes that are referenced on the AndroidManifest
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService


#To remove debug logs:
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static *** d(...);
public static *** v(...);
}

#To avoid changing names of methods invoked on layout's onClick.
# Uncomment and add specific method names if using onClick on layouts
#-keepclassmembers class * {
# public void onClickButton(android.view.View);
#}

#Maintain java native methods 
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native <methods>;
}

#To maintain custom components names that are used on layouts XML.
#Uncomment if having any problem with the approach below
#-keep public class custom.components.package.and.name.**

#To maintain custom components names that are used on layouts XML:
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
public <init>(android.content.Context);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

#Maintain enums
-keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

#To keep parcelable classes (to serialize - deserialize objects to sent through Intents)
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
 public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
} 

#Keep the R
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
public static <fields>;
}

###### ADDITIONAL OPTIONS NOT USED NORMALLY

#To keep callback calls. Uncomment if using any
#http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/examples.html#callback
#-keep class mypackage.MyCallbackClass {
#   void myCallbackMethod(java.lang.String);
#}

#Uncomment if using Serializable 
#-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
#    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
#    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
#    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
#    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
#    java.lang.Object readResolve();
#}
```